# Undefined Constant MYSQLI_ASYNC - Non blocking queries in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, nonblocking

I understand that mysqlnd allows non blocking queries. However, I'm trying:

```
// goes without saying this code works correctly when second parameter is ommitted
$link->query($myQuery, MYSQLI_ASYNC);
```

The error I get is:"Notice: use of undefined constant MYSQLI_ASYNC assumed 'MYSQLI_ASYNC' " 
and ensuing errors.

PHP Version: 5.3.5-1 ubuntu7.4

---

I don't know if I actually have mysqlnd installed/activated, and I can't find a good resource on how to tell if it is.

Help?

Comment: If the constant isn't defined, I'd say it isn't installed. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause for this is that the `mysqlnd` extension is not installed.  Please note, [according to docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php) any PHP version less than PHP 5.4 will need to explicitly configure to use `mysqlnd`; starting with PHP 5.4 `mysqlnd` will be enabled by default.

There are a couple different ways to tell if you have an extension loaded.

- [`phpinfo()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) should output a section labeled `mysqlnd`
- [`extension_loaded('extension_name')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php) should return true/false whether or not you have the extension loaded